# Use scala fastparse to remove enclosing escaped quotes but preserving the others

Tags: scala, fastparse

I want to use [fastparse](https://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/) to transform the following string `\"Escaped quote\"\"\"` into `Escaped quote\"`.  I have the following code which *almost* works.

```
def escapedQuote[_: P]: P[Unit] = P("\"")
def unquotedColumn[_: P] = P(escapedQuote ~ ((!escapedQuote ~ AnyChar.!) | escapedQuote ~ escapedQuote.!).rep ~ escapedQuote ~ End)
val result = parse(input, unquotedColumn(_))
```

I get the result `ArrayBuffer(E, s, c, a, p, e, d,  , q, u, o, t, e, ")` which is very close to what I want, however I want the result in a String.

However, when I try the following (adding .! after the rep),

```
def unquotedColumn[_: P] = P(escapedQuote ~ ((!escapedQuote ~ AnyChar.!) | escapedQuote ~ escapedQuote.!).rep.! ~ escapedQuote ~ End)
```

I get the result `Escaped quote\"\"`.  An extra escaped quote has appeared.

I want to use my `unquotedColumn` in other parsers.

Any ideas how to fix my code?

Comment: In the end I decided to write a custom parser instead